# Center the text in my navbar? Tried so many other things

Tags: menu, navbar, center

I have searched the site and tried many things, but cant accomplish my issue.  I am NEW to coding but I am reading studying and trying.  I have the following code. Just cant figure where to put "text align center" where it will work.  Thank you guys for any help.

```
<style>
    
.menu-btn {
    background-color: #8F070A;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border: none;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #8F070A;
   min-width: 160px;
   z-index: 1;
}
nav{
   background-color: #8F070A;
}
.links,.links-hidden{
   display: inline-block;
   color: black;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.links-hidden{
   display: block;
}
.links{
   display: inline-block;
}
.links-hidden:hover,.links:hover {
   background-color: white;
}
.dropdown-menu:hover .menu-content {
   display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu:hover .menu-btn {
   background-color: white;
}
    
</style>
```

Comment: Nevermaind I found it.  Thanks guys, sorry STILL learning and trying things.

Comment: No need to apologise, but you should create an answer to your own question so that others can benefit from it.